# compare primary/alias groups across two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Gday,

We have two tables that contain exactly the same structure. There are two columns "PrimaryAddress" and "AliasAddress". These are for email addresses and aliases. We want to find any records that need to be added to *either* side to keep the records in sync. The catch is that the primary name in one table might be listed as an alias in the other. The good news is that an address wont appear twice in the "AliasAddress" column.

```
TABLE A
PrimaryAddress~~~~~AliasAdress
chris@work~~~~~~~~~chris@home
chris@work~~~~~~~~~c@work
chris@work~~~~~~~~~theboss@work
chris@work~~~~~~~~~thatguy@aol
bob@test~~~~~~~~~~~test1@test
bob@test~~~~~~~~~~~charles@work
bob@test~~~~~~~~~~~chuck@aol
sally@mars~~~~~~~~~sally@nasa
sally@mars~~~~~~~~~sally@gmail

TABLE B
PrimaryAddress~~~~~AliasAdress
chris@home~~~~~~~~~chris@work
chris@home~~~~~~~~~c@work
chris@home~~~~~~~~~theboss@work
chris@home~~~~~~~~~thatguy@aol
bob@test~~~~~~~~~~~test1@test
bob@test~~~~~~~~~~~charles@work
sally@nasa~~~~~~~~~sally@mars
sally@nasa~~~~~~~~~sally@gmail
sally@nasa~~~~~~~~~ripley@nostromo
```

The expected result is to return the following missing records from both tables:

```
bob@test~~~~~~~~~~~chuck@aol
sally@nasa~~~~~~~~~ripley@nostromo
```

Note that the `chris@*` block is a total match because the sum of all the aliases (plus primary) is still the same regardless of which address is considered primary. It doesnt matter which address is primary as along as the sum of the entire primary group contains all entries in both tables.

I dont mind if this is run in two passes A->B and B->A but I just cant get my head around a solution.

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Sorry, but with the flip-flopping of column contents, I honestly can’t figure out the true requirements here. Can you add a bit more detail on what you are looking for, or perhaps rephrase it? (The use of “Primary” and “Sum” are particularly confusing to me.)

Comment: By "sum" I mean grouping of all rows for each primary address, selecting all addresses and then comparing the distinct result. In my example above, the "chris" records are considered the same in both tables because they have 4 rows that when combined in a list and duplicates removed, result in the same 5 email addresses.

Comment: What would need to be done if there were "overlapping" values? For example, if we added ("bob@test", "c@work") to Table A, would the "bob" and "chris" blocks now be considered to be one block?

Comment: That cant happen: "The good news is that an address wont appear twice in the "AliasAddress" column."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, This is how we did it... As it was becoming a pain, we ran a procedure that added the primary address of each entry as an alias: xx@xx -> xx@xx so that *all* addresses were listed as aliases for each user. This is similar to what @Phillip Kelly did above. Then we ran the following code: (its messy but it works; in one pass too)

```
SELECT 'Missing from B:' as Reason, TableA.[primary] as APrimary, TableA.[alias] as AAlias, TableB.[primary] as BPrimary,TableB.[alias] as BAlias into #A FROM dbo.TableA LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB ON TableB.alias = TableA.alias 
SELECT 'Missing from A:' as Reason,TableA.[primary] as APrimary, TableA.[alias] as AAlias, TableB.[primary] as BPrimary,TableB.[alias] as BAlias into #B FROM dbo.TableB LEFT OUTER JOIN TableA ON TableA.alias = TableB.alias 

select * from #A
select * from #B

UPDATE #A 
   SET #A.APrimary = #B.BPrimary 
   FROM #B  INNER JOIN  #A ON #A.APrimary = #B.BPrimary
   WHERE #A.BPrimary IS NULL

UPDATE #B 
   SET #B.BPrimary = #A.APrimary 
   FROM #B  INNER JOIN  #A ON #B.BPrimary = #A.BPrimary
   WHERE #B.APrimary IS NULL

select * from #A
select * from #B

select * into #result from (
select Reason, BPrimary as [primary], BAlias as [alias] from #B where APrimary IS NULL
union
select Reason, APrimary as [primary], AAlias as [alias] from #A where BPrimary IS NULL
) as tmp

select * from #result

drop table #A
drop table #B
drop table #result

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to compare table A and B, and find rows which are unqiue in either table. How about an [outer join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp), followed by looking for *NULL* values:

```
SELECT ta.*, tb.*

FROM       table_a ta

FULL OUTER JOIN table_b tb ON  tb.PrimaryAddress = ta.PrimaryAddress 
                           AND tb.AliasAddress = ta.AliasAddress

WHERE ta.PrimaryAddress IS NULL
   OR tb.PrimaryAddress IS NULL
```

If I understand the question correctly, this should return what you ask for.

Comment: Not quite unfortunately. Note that there are very few rows that match in this way. Here is the result of that query:  `chris@work chris@home NULL NULL
chris@work c@work NULL NULL
chris@work theboss@work NULL NULL
chris@work thatguy@aol NULL NULL
bob@test chuck@aol NULL NULL
sally@mars sally@nasa NULL NULL
sally@mars sally@gmail NULL NULL
NULL NULL chris@home chris@work
NULL NULL chris@home c@work
NULL NULL chris@home theboss@work
NULL NULL chris@home thatguy@aol
NULL NULL sally@nasa sally@mars
NULL NULL sally@nasa sally@gmail
NULL NULL sally@nasa ripley@nostromo`

Comment: Then I'm not quite sure what it is you want. The above query simply returns all entries which are unique to either table a or table b. Without any other information, this is (as far as I can tell) the only way to identify new entries.

Answer (score 0):

```
drop TABLE #TABLEA
CREATE TABLE #TABLEA
    ([PrimaryAddress] varchar(10), [AliasAdress] varchar(12))
;

INSERT INTO #TABLEA
    ([PrimaryAddress], [AliasAdress])
VALUES
    ('chris@work', 'chris@home'),
    ('chris@work', 'c@work'),
    ('chris@work', 'theboss@work'),
    ('chris@work', 'thatguy@aol'),
    ('bob@test', 'test1@test'),
    ('bob@test', 'charles@work'),
    ('bob@test', 'chuck@aol'),
    ('sally@mars', 'sally@nasa'),
    ('sally@mars', 'sally@gmail')
;


drop TABLE #TABLEB
CREATE TABLE #TABLEB
    ([PrimaryAddress] varchar(10), [AliasAdress] varchar(15))
;

INSERT INTO #TABLEB
    ([PrimaryAddress], [AliasAdress])
VALUES
    ('chris@home', 'chris@work'),
    ('chris@home', 'c@work'),
    ('chris@home', 'theboss@work'),
    ('chris@home', 'thatguy@aol'),
    ('bob@test', 'test1@test'),
    ('bob@test', 'charles@work'),
    ('sally@nasa', 'sally@mars'),
    ('sally@nasa', 'sally@gmail'),
    ('sally@nasa', 'ripley@nostromo')
;
```

try the following

```
select a.PrimaryAddress,a.AliasAdress  from #TABLEA a left join #TABLEB b on a.AliasAdress=b.AliasAdress or b.PrimaryAddress=a.AliasAdress 
where b.PrimaryAddress is null
union all
select a.PrimaryAddress,a.AliasAdress  from #TABLEB a left join #TABLEA b on a.AliasAdress=b.AliasAdress or b.PrimaryAddress=a.AliasAdress 
where b.PrimaryAddress is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it, with a bit of throwing-hands-up-in-the-air at the end.

Step one, identify the sets of items to be compared. This is:

- For a “primary” value, all values found in Alias
- Including the “primary” value as well (to cover that nasa/nostromo case)

A set in a table (A or B) is identified by its primary value. What really makes it hard is that the primary value is not shared across the two tables (sally@mars, sally@nasa). So we can compare sets, but we have to be able to “go back” to the primary on each table separately (e.g. the stand-out from table B may be sally@nasa / ripley@nostroomo, but we have to add sally@mars / ripley@nostromo to table A)

Major problems arise if, in a table, a primary value appears as an alias for a different primary value (e.g. in table A, chris@work appears as an alias for bob@test). For the sake of sanity, I am going to assume this will not happen… but if it does, the problem becomes even harder.

This query works to add missing items in B that are not in A, where the PrimaryAddress is the same for both A and B:

```
;WITH setA (SetId, FullSet)
 as (--  Complete sets in A
     select PrimaryAddress, AliasAdress   
      from A
     union select PrimaryAddress, PrimaryAddress
      from A
    )
,setB (SetId, FullSet)
 as (--  Complete sets in B
     select PrimaryAddress, AliasAdress   
      from B
     union select PrimaryAddress, PrimaryAddress
      from B
    )
,NotInB (Missing)
 as (--  What's in A that's not in B
     select FullSet
      from setA
     except select FullSet  --  This is the secret sauce. Definitely worth your time to read up on how EXCEPT works.
      from setB
    )
--  Take the missing values plus their primaries from A and load them into B
INSERT B (PrimaryAddress, AliasAdress)
 select A.PrimaryAddress, nB.Missing
  from NotInB nB
   inner join A
    on A.AliasAdress = nb.Missing
```

Run it again with the tables reversed (from “NotInB” on) to do the same for A.

**HOWEVER**

Doing so with your sample data for "in B not in A" will add (sally@nasa, ripley@nostromo) to A, and as that’s a different primary, it’d create a new set, and so does not solve the problem. It gets ugly quickly. Talking it out from here:

- Takes two passes, one for A not in B, one for B not in A
- For each pass, have to do two checks
- First check is what’s above: what’s in A not in B where primary addresses match, and add it
- Second check is ugly: what’s in A not in B where the primary addresses from A is NOT a primary address in B and, thus, must be an alias. Here, find A’s primary address in B’s alias list, get the primary key used for this set in B, and create the row(s) in B using those values.